# getting object from select element

Tags: html, reactjs, arrays, drop-down-menu, material-ui

Here i'm using select from material ui, and have a question: how to get an object (handleChange function) when user clicks from dropdown ?
in my handleChange i want to have object and not just 'name', and those places where i'm using 'selected' i could just pick it from object like this selected.name (if needed).
and another question: i'm getting data to 'selected' from api the thing is that that data shows on select itself but nothing shows in dropdown. any advices how to make this code simpler?

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-multiple-select-with-select-all-option-forked-ipukpk?file=/src/App.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import CreateIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Create";
import { MenuProps, useStyles } from "./utils";
import AddUser from "./AddUser";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import EditUser from "./EditUser";

function App() {
  const rawOptions = [
    { id: 1, name: "Oliver Hansen" },
    { id: 2, name: "Van Henry" }
  ];

  const classes = useStyles();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(rawOptions);
  const [openAddModal, setOpenAddModal] = useState(false);
  const [openUpdateModal, setOpenUpdateModal] = useState(false);
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState({
    id: null,
    name: ""
  });
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setSelected(value);
    console.log("get id and name of selected here", value);
  };

  function addUser(newArray) {
    const newTodos = [...options, newArray];

    setOptions(newTodos);
  }

  const openAddUser = () => {
    setOpenAddModal(true);
  };
  const openUpdateUser = (event, data) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    setOpenUpdateModal(true);
    setEdit(data);
  };
  // console.log("id", edit);
  const closeAddModal = () => {
    setOpenAddModal(false);
  };
  const closeUpdateModal = () => {
    setOpenUpdateModal(false);
  };

  const updateUser = (updateUser) => {
    setOptions(
      options.map((user) => (user.id === updateUser.id ? updateUser : user))
    );
  };

  return (
    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
      <div>
        <InputLabel id="mutiple-select-label">Multiple Select</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="mutiple-select-label"
          multiple
          variant="outlined"
          value={selected || []}
          onChange={handleChange}
          renderValue={(selected) => selected}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {options.map((option, index) => (
            <MenuItem key={index} value={option.name}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Checkbox checked={selected?.includes(option.name)} />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={option.name}>{option}</ListItemText>

              <DeleteIcon
                onClick={(e) => {
                  e.stopPropagation();
                  setOptions(options.filter((o) => o.id !== option.id));
                }}
              />
              <ListItemIcon>
                <CreateIcon
                  onClick={(e) =>
                    openUpdateUser(e, { id: option.id, name: option.name })
                  }
                />
              </ListItemIcon>
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
        <Button onClick={openAddUser} style={{ backgroundColor: "#287B7A" }}>
          Add User
        </Button>
      </div>
      <p>{selected}</p>

      <AddUser
        openAddModal={openAddModal}
        handleClose={closeAddModal}
        array={options}
        addUser={addUser}
      />

      <EditUser
        edit={edit}
        openUpdateModal={openUpdateModal}
        handleClose={closeUpdateModal}
        array={options}
        updateUser={updateUser}
      />
    </FormControl>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change `value` to the `id`

```
<MenuItem key={option.id} value={option.id}>
```

Since you need that to be guaranteed to be unique.

And also change the checkbox:

```
  <Checkbox checked={selected?.includes(option.id)} />
```

Then you will store an array of ids in the `selected` state.

```
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSelected(event.target.value);
  };
```

And if you ever need to get back to the options (it would be bad to store the whole option because it'd be duplicated state) you can do:

```
// If after the handlechange fn
selected.map((selectedId) => options.find(option => option.id === selectedId))

// If inside the handlechange fn
event.target.value.map((selectedId) => options.find(option => option.id === selectedId))
```

Also change `renderValue` to show the names in the box when they are selected:

```
          renderValue={(selected) =>
            selected
              .map(
                (selectedId) =>
                  options.find((option) => option.id === selectedId)?.name
              )
              .join(", ")
          }
```

You might want to break that map/find statement into a common function.

You also need to change the delete handler to clear out selected items that have been deleted:

```
              <DeleteIcon
                onClick={(e) => {
                  e.stopPropagation();
                  setSelected((prev) => prev.filter((id) => id !== option.id));
                  setOptions(options.filter((o) => o.id !== option.id));
                }}
              />
```

As for the selected items being fetched from the server and them being a list of names, you will need to work back from the names to the id.

```
const initialSelectedValues = selectedNamesFromServer.map((selectedName) => options.find(option => option.name === selectedName).id)
```

Note this seems a little like a bad API design since you should always use ID only. What happens if there are 2 people with the same name? Probably you wouldn't be able to select the second one as it can not be disambiguated. The server should return ids really.

Presumably, you have endpoints to do the following. I have recommended what to do or each (I don't know your URL scheme):

- HTTP GET the selected items from the server. This should return an array of IDs from the back end store/database and not really the names. Well, it could return both, but you shouldn't use the name from there even if you do, since it will break the handling of duplicates.
- HTTP POST the selected items back to the server. This should be changed to ingest an array of selected IDs only.
- HTTP POST a new item to the list when they click "add item". Not necessarily selected. If you don't have a way of managing the list you wouldn't be able to have an item that is added, but not selected. This would accept an object containing just the name, and then the server would create this in the store, and whilst doing so, persist an ID as well against that name in the store/db.
- HTTP DELETE an item from the list when they click "delete item". Note this is not about removing a selected item, it's about removing an option, which may not necessarily be selected since you allow new options that are unchecked. This would just accept the ID to delete and the backend would remove it from the store.
- HTTP GET all the items in the list, including selected and unselected. This would return an array of objects, each containing an `id` and `name`. This is what replaced `rawArray`.

Comment: thnx, from api i'm getting for example like this: ["Oliver Hansen","Van Henry"], how to transform data to a list of ids before passing to value ?

Comment: Gotcha let me edit my answer, give me some mins

Comment: Ok added. Note what I said that since the API doesn't return IDs there is a potential flaw.

Comment: Also you should change your `key` on `MenuItem` to the ID. It is usually bad to use indexes as a key as it is not necessarily stable. This will likely cause issues when you delete one if you don't change it as another option will assume the old ones `key` and they'd all shift up. This causes problems for react.

Comment: so it goes like this, this whole thing is a component, i add user from here and sumbit it to the server, and in another component i have exactly this same thing but there i'm getting this data i sent i'm getting back and i can update it or delete it (i'm getting same data back what i sent), so i should send id ?

Comment: Generally, you might need to change the server to operate based on an array of IDs. Both the API to get the selected IDs and the API to fetch all the options (name/id pairs), assuming they are also from server? The server would need to be able to cross reference the ID with the name. Using name is a potential dead end due to the duplication issue. It will work...until you have a duplicate name. That means you have a data structure issue.

Comment: If you never get the *whole list* of options from the server though (note: not talking about just selected here) that might change things. It only makes sense to use ID back and forth for the selected ones if those IDs are known to the server and mapped to a name on the server. Usually your database will do that.

Comment: i should be sending an object(where is both id and name) to the server ? and when it comes back i should be getting object ?

Comment: Well...depends. Firstly, one question: You state the selected items currently come from API. But does the whole list of options also come from the API (including unselected) or is that only client side?

Comment: in the beginning there is no data (this rawOptions is just test i add here) i add user by cliking 'ADD USER' and then i send that what i just added. Then that goes to server and i'm getting that same back so if i want to update it or delete it (very simple)

Comment: Gotcha. Yeh you should change the server. I will edit answer as this is noisy. Give me a sec.

Comment: Ive added a description of the endpoints you'd need and what ingests/returns what

Comment: You might be able to avoid using IDs everywhere if you added uniqueness constraints so that the user cant save back names that already exist in the DB to the server. But that could be a problem unless its usernames and not real names like it is now (latter could definitely have clashes)

Comment: one question before i accept your answer, you can try from that code, when you select one of them from dropdown for example 'Oliver Hansen' and then you go to edit that by clicking pencil, you can see that old value stays in select (not in dropdown), how to delete old value when that same is edited ?

Comment: so when 'Oliver Hansen' is updated to 'Oliver james' then that 'Oliver Hansen' shouldnt be there

Comment: Let me check that out.

Comment: I've added a fix to the answer on `renderValue`. Also here's a working code sandbox.

Comment: And edited one final time `renderValue` to not cause error when selected item is deleted. Though you also have a bug in that if a selected item is deleted you need to remove it from the selected items as well.

Comment: 'Also here's a working code sandbox.' you didnt give it :D

Comment: Lol woops. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-multiple-select-with-select-all-option-forked-bo9ob6?file=/src/App.js. Also adding a change to `onClick` handler of delete item to fix deletion of selected items -- edit: done

Comment: when you click edit pencil, that dialog goes behind dropdown, but i wont disturb you anymore, thnx for best explanation ! if you want can you upvote my question so other could find it (i will accept your answer)

Comment: To fix that remove `disablePortal` from the `Dialogu`

Comment: this question is answered, but one little thing i want to ask, how to prevent 'empty' or 'undefined', i mean dropdown and select should not accept empty as value,, should it be prevented from here renderValue={(selected) => selected .map( (selectedId) => options.find((option) => option.id === selectedId)?.name ) .join(", ") } ?

Comment: I think this would need form validation. You kind of have to allow empty initially as you need to begin with nothing selected. But its on form submission you'd check if its empty and render an error. If theres no "submit" button, you can keep track of if the user touched the field by setting some `touched` state on the `onBlur` handler of the select to `true.` Then in render do something like `{ touched &&  !selected && <div>You must fill this field!</div> }`

Answer (score 0):

```
 const handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setSelected(value);
     const filterObjects = options.filter((o) => value.includes(o.name))
console.log("get id and name of selected here", filterObjects);
  };
```

Comment: could you provide codesandbox, im getting an empty array

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-multiple-select-with-select-all-option-forked-4zujj6

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please "edit" to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer